# How to show Siri UI while siri reading the messages?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, siri, carplay

I have to implement notifications functionality in CarPlay by using siriKit. I able to show the notifications in carplay. when I click on the notification, siri reading it by default. my problem is that, I want to show the siri UI as below while siri reading the notifications. but I am unable to implement it.[image]

I have created Intent Extensions for messaging and added siri capability to the app. but I don't know how to use the those extesnions in CarPlay.

Answer (score 0):

use `CPMessageListItem`. this will automatically invokes SiriUI to read the content of the message.

about `CPMessageListItem`, you can see more information on official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpmessagelistitem?changes=_8

And you have to write your logic in `INSearchForMessagesIntent` handler for searching and delivering the content of the message to Siri.